# Prevent link used for focusing on input to navigate to hash URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs

We have an Anchor component which renders an `<a>` tag. Now, clicking on it does focus on the input element, but it immediately navigates. So say if my name is 'abc', it focusses on 'abc' input, but immediately naviages to this URL
http://localhost:3000/#/abc

Is it possible to not navigate to this URL? I do not have control over the Anchor component

```
<Anchor
  href={`#${name}`}
  onClick={() =>
    document.getElementsByName(name)?.[0].focus()
  }
>
  Test Link
</Anchor>
```

Comment: Why dont you not use anchor tag, instead use a span tag and add style to it. OR alternatively on click event, use event.preventDefault()
`onClick={(event) =>
    event.preventDefault()
    document.getElementsByName(name)?.[0].focus()
  }`

Comment: actually, i do not have control over the underlying component and there are other features i get by consuming that....consistent styling and all....so ...

Comment: Did event.preventDefault() worked ?

Comment: Actually i do not have control over the Anchor component itself....so looking at some other way... –

Comment: If you can't add `preventDefault()` to the click handler posted in your question, you could still add a wrapper `<div>` somewhere in the chain of ancestors and add `onClick={(e) => e.preventDefault()}`

Comment: Clicking some text to set focus to some input is usually just done with `<label for="id-of-input"> click me </label>`

Comment: @Martin : Let me try that and see...thanks a lot for your inputs

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to prevent the default navigation behavior when clicking on the anchor tag by using the `event.preventDefault()` method. You can modify your code as follows to prevent the navigation:

```
<Anchor
  href={`#${name}`}
  onClick={(event) => {
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent default navigation
    document.getElementsByName(name)?.[0].focus();
  }}
>
  Test Link
</Anchor>
```

By calling `event.preventDefault()` inside the `onClick` handler, you are telling the browser to prevent the default behavior of the anchor tag, which is to navigate to the specified URL. Instead, the focus will be set on the input element without navigating away from the current page.

Comment: Thanks...but actually i do not have control over the Anchor component itself....so looking at some other way...